# Django installation - trouble with creating a mysite directory

Tags: python, django, installation, python-2.6

I have installed django on windows but I am having trouble with the step where you are supposed to create a new project directory and then run `django-admin.py startproject mysite`.  When I do this, I get the output below but no new mysite directory is created in my project directory.  What is going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should remove dot from the end of a string.

```
python django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Comment: It doesn't make a difference.  I tried it without the dot and it does the same thing

Comment: did you do it with running through calling python and not the script directly? Does your directory mysite already exist?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you have `.py` in `%PATHEXTS%`. But in all probability it's not set up to pass on command line arguments - the default only registers .py files to run `python.exe $1`, not `python.exe $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9` (unfortunately it doesn't support `$*`). The easiest way to deal with it is to run `C:\path\to\python C:\path\to\django-admin.py startproject mysite`.

Answer (score 0):

Read this

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#startproject-projectname

> This command is disabled when the
>   --settings option to django-admin.py is used, or when the environment
>   variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE has
>   been set. To re-enable it in these
>   situations, either omit the --settings
>   option or unset
>   DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.